# How can I load and sort button controls dynamically, based on changing data?

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, controls

So I have a database 'Restaurant', with a table 'dining_tables'.

In my C# application, I am attempting to count the amount of tables in the 'dining_tables' table, then creating a button for each of those tables, and dynamically placing them on the form, side by side, and in rows.

- 5 buttons per row. (Not sure how to line-break the buttons efficiently after every 5 buttons)

This is how I'm fetching the tables from the database:

(SQL is a class I made for simplying the sql tasks)

```
SqlDataReader dr = SQL.queryExec("SELECT * FROM tables");
while(dr.Read()){
var tblName = dr["tbl_Name"];
}
```

^ Now that I am extracting the name for each table, I have done the following.

1) Create a button, style it, and apply the current 'tblName' to the the text property of the button.
2) Add the button to the form.

What I'm stuck on now, is finding out how to align the buttons vertically on the form for every tbl_Name, and then continuing on a new line after every 5 buttons.

Note: I intend to later refine this by adding pages, but for now I want to know how to accomplish the above.

Any positive support will be much appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What kind of application? Winforms? WPF? Web?

Comment: winform application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using flowLayoutPanel?
it is a control panel that will align and position all controls inside it automatically for yourself it has 4 direction in the property FlowDirection, try using that and I think you will just have to use this configurations

```
flowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
flowLayoutPanel.WrapContents = true;
```

you will just have to calculate how many width 5 buttons have, plus its magin then set it to be the width of your flowLayoutPanel

Answer (score 0):

```
       SqlDataReader dr = SQL.queryExec("SELECT * FROM tables");            
       int i = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = dr["tbl_Name"].ToString();
            btn.Width = 100;
            btn.Height = 50;
            btn.Left = (i % 5) * 110;
            btn.Top = (i / 5) * 60;
            Controls.Add(btn);
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Simply

```
SqlDataReader dr = SQL.queryExec("SELECT * FROM tables");
int i = 0;
while (dr.Read())Controls.Add(new Button() {Text = dr["tbl_Name"].ToString(), 
Size = new Size(100, 50), Location = new Point(i % 5 *110, i++ / 5 * 60) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sayka's answer is the best one when it comes to using pure code without other controls to generate a formula that can properly align 5 buttons and line-break after them.

However, I personally found the flowlayoutpanel to be the best option for me as the Scroll functionality helps me escape from having to input pages.